# `[NSScreen mainscreen]` misleading documentation

Tags: objective-c

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscreen/1388371-mainscreen?language=objc) for `[NSScreen mainscreen]` is misleading.

> The main screen is not necessarily the same screen that contains the menu bar or has its origin at (0, 0). The main screen refers to the screen containing the window that is currently receiving keyboard events. It is the main screen because it is the one with which the user is most likely interacting.

I try:

```
printf( "%p \n", [NSScreen mainScreen]);

for( NSScreen* sc in [NSScreen screens] ) {
    NSRect f = [sc frame];
    printf("%p    %f %f %f %f  \n", sc,  f.origin.x, f.origin.y, f.size.width,f.size.height );
}
```

I drag my Xcode window to my Native MacBook display, ensure it has keyboard focus, and execute:

```
0x1006aaac0 
0x1006aaac0    0.000000 0.000000 2560.000000 1440.000000  
0x1006ab3d0    0.000000 -800.000000 1280.000000 800.000000
```

Now I drag it to my LCD, ensure it has keyboard focus, and execute:

```
0x1005a15e0 
0x1005a15e0    0.000000 0.000000 2560.000000 1440.000000  
0x1005a64c0    0.000000 -800.000000 1280.000000 800.000000
```

So `[NSScreen mainscreen]` each time identifies the LCD (the one with the menubar).

So it appears that `[NSScreen mainscreen]`, *contrary to the documentation*, does in fact yield the screen with the menubar.

Would someone care to confirm this as a documentation bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What does the position of Xcode's window have to do with it? The program querying it is presumably not Xcode itself, but your app.

Anyway, this is affected by System Preferences > Mission Control > Displays have separate spaces. Also, see the [10.9 AppKit release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/index.html#10_9Spaces):

> ### Spaces and Multiple Screens
>
> In 10.9, we have added a feature where each screen gets its own set of
>   spaces, and it is possible to switch between spaces on one screen
>   without perturbing the spaces on the other screens. In this mode, a
>   fullscreen window uses one screen, and leaves the contents of any
>   other screens unchanged.
>
> Each screen now has its own menu bar, and it is possible to show the
>   Dock on any screen, provided you have the Dock set to “Position on
>   Bottom”.
>
> The menu bar has an active appearance on the active screen, which is
>   typically the screen containing the key window. Menu bars on other
>   screens have an inactive appearance.
>
> In this mode, it is desirable for new windows to open on the active
>   screen. In support of this model, +[NSScreen mainScreen] now returns
>   the active screen, which is slightly different than its prior behavior
>   of returning the screen containing the keyWindow, if any, and the zero
>   screen otherwise.
>
> A window restored at app launch through -restoreStateWithCoder: will
>   return to its previous location, independent of active screen. A
>   window positioned using -setFrameAutosaveName: will prefer the active
>   display.
>
> This feature can be disabled by unchecking the preference named
>   “Displays have Separate Spaces” in the Mission Control preference pane
>   in System Preferences. This setting only takes effect after logging
>   out and back in, or restarting. NSScreen has API to query whether the
>   separate space feature is enabled:
>
> ```
> + (BOOL)screensHaveSeparateSpaces NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_9);
> ```
>
> When this feature is enabled, windows may not visibly span displays. 
>   A window will get assigned to the display containing the majority of
>   its geometry if programmatically positioned in a spanning position.  A
>   window will get assigned to the display containing the mouse if the
>   window is moved by the user.  A window clips to the edge of the
>   display, whether or not there is another adjacent display.

Unfortunately, a lot of important information is only in the release notes. It's not always incorporated into the primary documentation.

Note the slightly different explanation of the "old" behavior of `+mainScreen`:

> … its prior behavior
>   of returning the screen containing the keyWindow, if any, and the zero
>   screen otherwise.

Consider that, for an inactive app or one with no windows, `-[NSApplication keyWindow]` will be `nil`, so `+mainScreen` will return the zero screen. So, with reference to the documentation you quoted:

> The main screen refers to the screen containing the window that is currently receiving keyboard events.

what was left unsaid is "in the calling app".

Anyway, if what you want is the primary display, the one at (0, 0), just use `NSScreen.screens[0]`.